# How to connect to MySQL database in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to MySQL DB with a PHP script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

But I don't get the message: "Connected successfully".

What's the problem?

Comment: So do you get an error message ?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Comment: Is your Apache/MySQL server on your PC or are you running this in a hosting account

Comment: your title is misleading as this has nothing to do with your IDE

Comment: MySQL server is running on my PC

Comment: So you should know the account name and password. If it is a vanilla setup of MySQL there should be a default super user account called `root` so try `$username = "root";
$password = "";`

Comment: MySQL is running on xampp.Is there a way to know the username and the password from xampp?

Comment: Windows or linux

Comment: The operating system is : windows   7

Comment: So have you tried `$username = "root"; $password = "";`

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: DOes phpMyAdmin work?

Comment: yes, phpMyAdmin works

Comment: try this one `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","<your database name here>");`

Comment: Well use that to either CREATE a user account with a password and use that. OR CHANGE the root password to something so you know what it is

Comment: @BadshahSahib Database name is not a required field

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: You could also try `$servername = "127.0.0.1";`... maybe you forgot to setup `localhost` in your HOSTS file!

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah! i know but i meant to say @yoni need to change his username and password in `mysqli()`

Comment: i tried this code works fine there is no error found when i change the username and password with my own

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Ok so your firewall could also be part of the problem. Check that mysql is allowed to get through port 3306 in your firewall

Answer (score 2):

### **Step 1**

Open your project in PhpStorm and open the DataSource window:

- Click on `View -> Tool Windows -> Database`
- Click on the Database sidebar, click on `new -> Datasource -> MySQL` The configuration window will appear

[image]

### **Step 2**

configure the ssh tunnel
Open your terminal.

```
cd ~/path/to/your/project
```

Display the configuration of your ssh connection with the command vagrant `ssh-config`

1. On the configuration window, click on the `SSH/SSL tab`
2. Report the host, user and port
3. Choose the Auth Type “Key pair (OpenSSH)” and report the path of the IdentityFile
   `config_ssh_vagrant`

Click on the apply and then click on Test Connection, you should see an error message saying you’ve got the wrong user/password combination

### Step 3

Set up the database configuration

In PhpStorm :
Click on the General tab of the configuration of your datasource
Fill the credentials, host and port. If you’re using `Symfony`, you can find it in the `parameters.yml` file.
Click on Apply
Finally, click on Test Connection

- Case 1 -> It works! congratulations you can now manipulate your DB from within your IDE
- Case 2 -> You get a wrong user/password combination error. Don’t panic! just do the following:

  `SSH` into your `Vagrant`: `vagrant ssh`
  Change to root user: `sudo su`
  Log as root user to your MySQL DB: `mysql -uroot`
  Run the following queries (don’t forget to replace yourdatabase, youruser and your_password):

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'your_user'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'your_password';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```

You now have granted your user to login to using the host “127.0.0.1”
You can now go to PhpStorm and test your connection again and it should work!

Answer (score -2):

First, in case you forgot. You need to change `$servername`, `$username` and `$password`based on your database connection data. If it doesn't work, you need to ensure that your connection data is right, e.g: by trying to authenticate it using phpmyadmin, sqlyog, etc.

Answer (score -3):

I just replaced the `$username='root'` and `$password=''` and it works for me. i think you need to write your phpmyadmin username and password below. and possibly you have problem with you phpmyadmin.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
die("Connected successfully");
}
```

Comment: If you read the comments, OP already tried that 15 minutes before you gave this answer

Comment: You were confusing him as i have seen.